# Nginx container won't build after running docker-compose up (volume device issue)

Tags: docker, nginx, certbot

**EDIT**: For those working on a Mac, if you get the message below, it's because you're not pointing to the correct file path on your host machine. I was working on making sure everything built/ran locally but eventually this will be hosted on a linux box on Digital Ocean and I will have to change the file path.

Initially, I didn't understand the functionality behind Volumes but this video really cleared things up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2PH_YPCsis

---

I'm currently writing a Docker Compose YAML file to run services like a Node.js app, MongoDB, and Nginx. While the app and db build, the webserver is giving me the error:

> ERROR: for webserver  Cannot start service webserver: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe path /User/alan/test\r\nis not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File S

I'm not too sure why it's giving me this error but I know that it's related to the `volumes/web-root/driver_opts/device` volume.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=db
      - MONGO_PORT=$MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_DB=$MONGO_DB 
    ports:
      - "81:8080"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: ./wait-for.sh db:27017 -- /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon index.js

  db:
    image: mongo:4.1.8-xenial
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
    volumes:  
      - dbdata:/data/db   
    networks:
      - app-network  
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  webserver:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email boyce.alan15@gmail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging -d bittap.io  -d www.bittap.io

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /User/alan/test
      o: bind
  dbdata:
  node_modules:  

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: In the `device:` line towards the end, should `/User` be `/Users` with an "s"?  That would cause the error you show.

Comment: Thanks David, that worked! I also realized I needed to learn more about the functionality of volumes in general in relation to containers vs on the host file system.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message, you are running macOS and Docker 4 Mac.

As Devid Maze said, you did a mistake in the `device:` attribute from the volumes.

Update the `volumes` section like that:

```
volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /Users/alan/test
      o: bind
```

Clear everything and retry it.